# Spring method security SpEL annotations always give 401 after upgrading Spring-boot to 3.2.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-annotations, spring-el

When upgrading from spring-boot 3.2.1 to 3.2.2 one the following SPEL security annotations stopped working. Now, it always gives a 401. Apparently, Spring security version did not upgrade between the two versions. The annotation that includes the ID works, but the one that uses the object doesn't.

**This one DOES NOT work:**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#organization, 'WRITE')")
<S extends Organization>S save(S organization);
```

**This one works:**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'com.company.app.Organization', 'READ')")
Optional<Organization> findById(Long id);
```

I don't even see anything in the logs that can help me identify the problem. It has worked in all versions prior to spring-boot 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in the Spring-boot 3.2.2 / Spring Framework 6.1.3

Parameter based cache keys on repository methods can't resolve after 6.1.2->6.1.3

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39261
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32087

**Solution will be released in 3.2.3**